# Find relations on the real number: transitive and/or antisymmetric

Tags: analysis, relations, real-numbers, symmetric-functions

$$I\  am\  searching\  for\  a\  relation\  on\  the\  real numbers\  (\mathbb R ),\  which\  sould\  be:$$

1. antisymmetric and transitive
2. antisymmetric and NOT transitive
3. NOT antisymmetric ,but transitive
4. NOT antisymmetric and NOT transitive

---

My ideas:

1. antisymmetric and transitive :   $$ the "\leq" relation  $$
   $$ antisym:  x\leq y \wedge y\leq x \Rightarrow x=y$$
   $$   trans: x\leq y\wedge y\leq z \Rightarrow x\leq z $$

---

2. antisymmetric and NOT transitive: $$\neq relation$$

   $$antisym:  x\neq y \wedge y\neq x\Rightarrow x\neq y $$
   $$ trans:  Example: 2\neq 3 \wedge 3\neq 2 \Rightarrow 2\neq 2   => contradiction!$$

---

3. NOT antisymmetric ,but transitive:   $$ "<" relation $$

$$ antisym: x<y \wedge  y<x \Rightarrow that's\  always\  wrong!$$
$$ trans:  x<y \wedge y<z \Rightarrow x<z$$

---

4. NOT antisymmetric and NOT transitive: $$ xRy \Leftrightarrow |x-y|=1$$

$$ antisym: 0R1 \wedge 1R0 $$
$$ trans:  0R1 \wedge 1R0  \Rightarrow 0R2 \ \ contradiction!$$

---

Questions:
Are my relations right?
I think there is a mistake in the antisymmetric case of relation 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Correct.

2) $\neq$ is **not** antisymmetric (and not transitive, so it can be used for 4). For that $[x\neq y\wedge y\neq x]\Rightarrow x=y$ must be true, and that is not the case.

3) $<$ is antisymmetric. This because $\neg[x<y\wedge y<x]$ is true and consequently $\neg[x<y\wedge y<x]\vee x=y$ (equivalent with: $[x<y\wedge y<x]\Rightarrow x=y$) is true.

4) Correct.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Do you have correct examples for 2. and 3. ?

Comment: $R=\{(0,1),(1,2)\}$ is antisymmetric and not transitive.

Comment: $R=\{(0,1),(1,0),(0,0),(1,1)\}$ is transitive and not antisymmetric.